# Ruby on Rails: How to work with RDS MySQL instance locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rds, mysql-8.0, ruby-on-rails-6

### Environment

- `Rails version: 6.0.0.rc2`
- `Ruby version: ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580)`
- `RDS MySql:  Ver 8.0.15`

### Problem

I am trying to connect my RDS MySQL8 instance to my local Ruby on Rails application for testing purposes. My app is working fine with a local version of `MySQL8.0.12` with the `mysql2` gem.

When I use the RDS DB's details and I run `bin/rake db:[anything] VERBOSE=true` in the command line, it just hangs without giving ANY information on why it isn't working. Output below.

This is purely to test the db I want to use for a staging environment.

- I've connected to the RDS DB from the command line and DBeaver from my local machine, and I've been able to create new tables, so security groups should be ok.
- I've used the db connection test script below to ensure that `ActiveRecord::Base.connected` is true
- Connected, initiated, migrated and seeded a local mysql db just in case.

`database.yml`

```rb
#
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: [aws_rds_host_url]
  username:  <%= ENV.fetch("DB_USERNAME") %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_PASSWORD") %>
  database: db_name
```

test script found somewhere on stackoverflow (returns "CONNECTED!")

```rb
require './config/environment.rb' # Assuming the script is located in the root of the rails app
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection # Establishes connection
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection # Calls connection object
  puts "CONNECTED!" if ActiveRecord::Base.connected?
  puts "NOT CONNECTED!" unless ActiveRecord::Base.connected?
rescue StandardError => e
  puts e
  puts "rescue:: NOT CONNECTED!"
end
```

Running `bin/rake db:create VERBOSE=true` ||  `bin/rake db:migrate VERBOSE=true` (or anything `rake db:`) keeps hanging, tried for more than an hour. It does not make any changes to the DB. Stopped with cmd+C it just returns:

```rb
bin/rake db:create VERBOSE=true                                                                                                                                                        
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
    14: from bin/rake:3:in `<main>'
    13: from bin/rake:3:in `load'
    12: from [home]/[project dir]/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from [home]/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    10: from [home]/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from [home]/[project dir]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from [home]/[project dir]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
     7: from [home]/[project dir]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from [home]/[project dir]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
     5: from [home]/[project dir]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
     4: from [home]/[project dir]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:35:in `call'
     3: from [home]/[project dir]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:42:in `warm_run'
     2: from [home]/[project dir]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:62:in `run'
     1: from [home]/[project dir]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in `verify_server_version'
[home]/[project dir]/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in `gets': Interrupt
```